# How can we excite transverse magnetic or electric ( TM or TE) modes on metallic mediums?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, resource-recommendations, maxwell-equations, antennas

I would be very thankful if someone can point me at references on explaining theories of excitations for transverse magnetic or electric modes.

In engineering, the literature has plenty of papers on the subject where authors adopted antenna theory to specify launcher design.

I'm finding it hard to accept without theoretical foundations explaining the fundamental elements for exciting TM or TE modes.

Comment: Excite the EM wave, then choose the orientation of your device such that the incident wave is either TE or TM polarized.

Comment: This is discussed in *ecxruciatingly* great detail in Collin: Field Theory of Guided Waves, chapter 7 "Excitation of Waveguides and Cavities". Good luck!

Comment: Many thanks Gilbert, that's what I'm doing currently, but mode conversion is highly inefficient due to poor impedance matching. Any thoughts on this ?